# How to stop comments or like email notification on SharePoint news posts for a particular SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Could you please tell how can I stop getting email notification for SharePoint news posts or pages for a particular SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do it

**1. Stop following the site**

- Click on the SharePoint Logo. You'll navigate to the **SharePoint Home**.
- Unfollow all sites you don't care about:

[image]

**2. Unsubscribe from the emails**

- Open the email from Microsoft that you don't want to get any longer.
- At the bottom of the email find the link that says "unsubscribe" or "stop getting these emails". Click on it.

Comment: I can not unfollow sites, because that feature is being used to fetch news posts in news webpart from followed sites. 
2. If I unsubscribe from the email then I will  get no email notification from all news posts from all sites ... right?.

I would like to stop getting comments notification from few particular sites.

Comment: I see. it's not possible to control these notificaitons beyond what I've described, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you know if we could have customised solution for this comment section and what kind of solution do you suggest?

Comment: I don't know if there is a 3rd party solution for this. I had to build a custom solution for one of the clients that let every user select sites they want to monitor. And then every user would get a personalized roll-up of latest comments for each site they monitor.